# ASP.NET MVC app cannot connect to Azure SQL

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database, umbraco7

I have created a database in Azure SQL. I have updated firewall so that my local machine and dev server can hit the database. I have tested on both machines using the credentials using SQL Server Enterprise Manager all connects fine.

When I use the same server details and credentials in my `web.config`, it cannot connect - I get this error:

> A connection string is configured but Umbraco cannot connect to the database

The website is an umbraco cms website.

I have tried recreating the database, and also deleting reading the login and user still no joy.

Comment: can we see your connection string? please hide sensitive info :)

Comment: <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=xxx.database.windows.net;database=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source={dbServer};initial catalog={databaseName};persist security info=True;user id={userID};password={userPassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

please try this just change {} to your configuration

Comment: ok mystery solved epic fail on my part in the db name i had - changed it to _ not it works. i am guessing ranton187 your suggestion would have also fixed this